# Programmatically view content of html element loaded from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, src

I would like to get the contents of a file on the server into a string. What is the easiest way to do this? Right now I am trying:

```
 <script type="text/template" src="partials/someTemplate.html" 
 id="someTemplate"></script>

 <script>
  console.log($('#someTemplate').html()); //nothing comes up
 </script>
```

A hacky way to do this is:

```
 $('<div>').appendTo(document.body)
 .load('partials/someTemplate.html', function () {console.log(this.innerHTML);} );
```

and then get the innerHTML of that, but that's a waste of an HTML element. Any thoughts? I feel like this should be silly easy.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
var html;

$.get('partials/someTemplate.html', function(res)
{
    html = res;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to use an asynchronous server request (ajax) to get the content of a file and process it later.

This can be done in pure JavaScript using [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) but the most popular and easiest way to do this is using [jQuery's $.ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: "partials/someTemplate.html"
}).done(function( content ) {
    console.log( "Your returned content is " + content );
});
```

You can configure this ajax call in many ways as described in documentation, you can pass parameters to the file, cache the request or demand a specific content type to be returned if that is necessary, but given example would do just fine for what you are trying to accomplish.

Please note that there are many ways to do an ajax request in jQuery, like .load(), $.post(), $.get(), $.getScript() and $.getJSON() but those are all just shorthand methods for an Ajax request so if you use those you are basically using an $.ajax with some predefined parameters.

Also, make sure that you need to use JavaScript and an async request at all. Getting content of a file inside some other file is mostly often done using some server side processing language like PHP ([require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)),.NET, Java etc.,  and while that seems obvious for some people I felt obligated to say that since you didn't provide enaugh information about why you need that content and what you want to do with it.